# Limit Tags display and ad Drop Down Menu

Tags: wp-query, tags

Does anyone have any idea on how i can limit the number of tags shown in a post and if there is more it's a drop down menu.

Here's an example of what i mean.

[image]

Se where it sats "More On" those are the tags, I want to be able to show only 3 tags and then after that a drop down menu for the rest of the tags.

Is this possible, If so how can I do this. Only Tags Attached To The Post

Answer (score 0):

This can be a start...

```
<?php
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post_id);
$html = '<div class="post_tags">';
$i=1;
foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
    $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );  
    if($i>3)
    {
        if($i==4)
        {
            $html .= '<ul class="post_tags_menu">';
        }
        $html .= "<li><a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
        $html .= "{$tag->name}</a><li>";
    }
    else
    {
        $html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
        $html .= "{$tag->name}</a>";
    }
    $i++;
}
if($i>4)
{
    $html .= "</ul>";
}
$html .= '</div>';
echo $html;
?>
```

How to get post tags
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_tags

Comment: Only Tags Attached to the post not all tags

Comment: @MihadAiko have edited my answer, please look..

Comment: I don't even know where to begin with that :( @Rajeev

Comment: Does Anyone else have an answer